# Dynamically drawing multiple borders with MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using React 17 and MUI 5.6. I have a component that needs to add new borders to the parent container based on user input. I found some non-MUI [CSS tutorials](https://www.educba.com/css-multiple-borders/) for achieving what I want, but their borders are statically coded in CSS and not added on user demand.

[Here's a working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-swanson-d0rh50?file=/src/App.js) for one border. Would appreciate any help on how to support multiple borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help to solve your problem. Here is the working code, user can decide color with buttons but you can implement same solution also with dropdown options. https://codesandbox.io/embed/wonderful-worker-g8fzyi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

    export default function App() {
      const [colors, setColors] = useState([]);
      const [pixel, setPixel] = useState(6);
      const addColor = async (color) => {
        setPixel(pixel + 2);
        let randomColor = `0 0 0 ${pixel}px ${color}`;
        setColors([...colors, randomColor]);
      };
    
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            width: "100vw",
            height: "100vh",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            flexDirection: "column"
          }}
        >
          <Box
            sx={{
              width: "50%",
              height: "20%",
              border: 3,
              boxShadow: colors.join(",")
            }}
          ></Box>
          <div style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
            <Button onClick={() => addColor("#FFFF00")}>Yellow</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => addColor("#FF002B")}>Red</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => addColor("#0000FF")}>Blue</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => addColor("#2BFF00")}>Green</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```